# How to close ons-modal when the user clicks outside

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using ons-modal to display progress indicator.

```
<ons-modal var="postModal">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
  <br>
  <br> Please wait...
</ons-modal>
```

I need to hide the modal when the user clicks outside of it, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-click='postModal.hide()'` to `<ons-modal var='postModal'>` . Hope that helps